# How do you autocomplete in C9 IDE?

Tags: cloud9-ide

When I'm using c9 IDE and the autocomplete pops up, how do I replace my word with their suggestion? I tried double clicking, and it didn't replace. I looked at the documentation at https://docs.c9.io/docs/autocompletion and couldn't find how.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Autocomplete using tab. You may also choose the the word you want to complete with using up and down arrows.

Comment: Tab worked. Enter didn't, and clicking on the word I wanted to complete with didn't either.